# How does rclone perform remote checksum, and what is its effect on bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth, checksum

I'm trying to store photos on amazon cloud drive using rclone, and whenever I upload a batch of photos, both my upload and download spikes as reported by my ISP. So if I upload 75 GB, my monthly bandwidth usage increases by  approximately 150 GB. Is rclone simply pulling the data back to verify integrity, or is the checksum calculated remotely? I'm using rclone copy source dest.